# Header location for ajax call in response

Tags: asp.net, ajax, asp.net-web-api

Our project consist from two parts client side(knokout) and server side (ASP.Net MVC and WebAPI).

Client side often call the Web API to get/create/update data on the server. 
We handle it in below way (example for update)

```
public HttpResponseMessage UpdateEntity(EntityWE entity)
{

    HttpResponseMessage response;

    try
    {
        var updateEntity = this.someBl.UpdateEntity(entity);

        response = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.Created, updateEntity);
        response.Headers.Location = new Uri(Url.Link(WebApiRoutNames.CustomApi, new { id = updatedEntity.PageId }));

    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Logger.Error(ex);
        response = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError);
    }

    return response;
}
```

The question is why do we need to send header location in response for ajax call? 
Is `response = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.Created, updateEntity)` not enough?;

We don't use any redirection in response to ajax call

P.S. all the people who wrote this are far away... and I can't understand the reason why it was added to all Web API Controllers

Thanks in advance for any clarification.

Answer (score 0):

As I understand it you just want some clarification on why the Location header is added to the Ajax responses.

Normally the location header is there for redirect responses (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_location), though it seems to me in this case that maybe the backend is quite old? Maybe there was no Ajax on the client side to begin with and Location was used to redirect the browser to the newly updated/added entity.

This could be a classic case of split frontend/backend team. Where backend does not quite understand the frontend and vice versa. The backend has always added Location as that is how web applications were built before, redirecting to new resources. So either by old habit or documentation the backend team thinks they need the Location header still, because they never really knew what it did when it reached the client. I do not mean to state that this is the case here, but just talking from experience :-)

You are perfectly right that it is not needed on Ajax calls though, unless the ajax response grabs that header and uses it for some strange reason!

Comment: On client side we don't use the location header, so I thought maybe asp.net on behalf of us doing something with it... anyway thanks for the clarification